# Facebook 'feed' dialog disappears and stops the calling activity - Android

Tags: android, facebook

In one of the activities in my Android app I want the user to be able to post something to there wall on facebook. So far I have successfully allowed the user to log in using `facebook..authorize(this, new DialogListener() {` ... and this seems to work fine.

Now I am trying to use the following code in a Button `onClickListener` to allow the user to post something to there own wall.

```
facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.v("error", e.toString());

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    Log.v("error", e.toString());

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }});
```

It appears to work as it shows the dialog but it disappears after about 2 or 3 seconds and also seems to close the activity from where it was called.

Logcat isn't very helpful... the last log just prints the url and doesn't show an error or anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like its the same issue as this:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/282710765082535

Except that I was using Android 2.1. Changed to 2.2 and it now works fine